# Creating a new nested list element that is a combination of two existing nested list elements (in R)

Tags: r, apply, netcdf

I am looking for a hint about how to create a new nested list element from two existing nested list elements. In the current form of the script I am working on, I create a list called tardis that is n elements long, based on the number of elements in an input list. In the example blow, that input list, dataLayers, is 2 elements long.

After creating tardis, the script populates it by reading in data from 1200 netCDF files. Each of the 12 elements in 'mean' and 'sd' in tardis are matrices of geographic data, tardis[['data']][[decade]][['mean']][[month]], for example, for the 12 calendar months. When the list is fully populated I would like to create some derived variables. For example, in the snippet below, I would like to create a variable TOTALPRECIP by adding SNOW and RAIN. In doing this, I would like to create TOTALPRECIP from SNOW + RAIN as a third list element in tardis with the exact nested structure as the other two elements (adding them together and preserving the structure).

Is this possible with apply or its related functions?

```
begin <- 1901
end <- 1991
dataLayers <- c("SNOW","RAIN")
tardis<-list()
for (i in 1:length(dataLayers)){
  tardis[[dataLayers[i]]]<-list('longName'='timeLord','units'='theDr','data'=list())
  for (j in seq(begin,end,10)){
    tardis[[dataLayers[[i]]]][['data']][[as.character(j)]]<-list('mean'=vector(mode='list',length=12),'sd'=vector(mode='list',length=12))
   }
 }

#add SNOW AND RAIN

print(names(tardis))

>[1] "SNOW" "RAIN" "TOTALPRECIP"
```

Comment: why so many lists? Why not a data.frame?

Comment: I have been teaching myself R coming from Python (and dictionaries). I will investigate an alternate form of this script using data.frame. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Gotcha.  data.frames are essentially lists, neatly organized.  They display more cleanly and are easier to access specific data points.  The advantage to lists over data.frames is that the lists can be ragged where as in a data.frame, each column needs to have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your `for` loops using `replicate`  *(Note that the `expression` value for each `replicate` is the same expression you have in the assignment portion of your `for` loop)*

```
## This is your inner for-loop, using replicate
inds <- seq(begin, end, 10)
datas <- replicate(length(inds), list('mean'=vector(mode='list',length=12),'sd'=vector(mode='list',length=12))
                    , simplify=FALSE)
names(datas) <- inds

# This is your outer loop
tardis2 <- replicate(length(dataLayers), list('longName'='timeLord','units'='theDr','data'=datas)
                    , simplify=FALSE)
names(tardis2) <- dataLayers

# Compare Results
identical(tardis2, tardis)
# [1] TRUE
```

**However, I'm not sure if `list`s are relaly the best structure for this.   Have you considered `data.frame`s?**

Comment: I will implement this suggestion. In general, should I be using replicate in place of nested loops for data creation in R?

Comment: If the purpose of the for loop is to create or modify some data, generally, lapply & replicate will be what you need